# I want to select media files from drive and play them instead of giving a certain path in my javafx code

Tags: java, javafx

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String path =new File("E:\\500 Days Of Summer.2009.720p.BDRip.x264-VLiS\\500 Days Of Summer.2009.720p.BDRip.x264-VLiS.mp4").getAbsolutePath();
    me = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
    mp=new MediaPlayer(me);
    mv.setMediaPlayer(mp);
    //mp.setAutoPlay(true);

    DoubleProperty width = mv.fitWidthProperty();
    DoubleProperty height = mv.fitHeightProperty();
    width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "width"));
    height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mv.sceneProperty(), "height"));


    volume.setValue(mp.getVolume() * 100);
    volume.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {

        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.setVolume(volume.getValue() / 100);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider reviewing this link and editing your post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: have a look at using [javafx file chooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm)